# How to use the value of a SELECT as a column name in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I ask for your help because I can not determine a solution to this problem. I am using SQL Server 2014.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    event_id, 
    CONCAT ('week', CHARINDEX('Y', weeks), '_date') AS num 
FROM 
    CT_EVENT
```

which returns a week number of the form: `week1_date`

This value is the name of a column in another table. What I would like to do is a subrequest to get the value that is in it.

```
SELECT week1_date 
FROM CT_CONFIG
```

I looked for a way to 'caster' a string in column name without actually finding.

Thank you in advance, and remain available for any supplement.

Jérémy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Sub-query here, you will need to use Dynamic sql, something like this...

```
Declare   @ColumnName SYSNAME
        , @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ColumnName =  CONCAT ('week', CHARINDEX ('Y', weeks), '_date')  
FROM CT_EVENT

SET @Sql = N' SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' FROM CT_CONFIG;'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql;
```

Comment: Works, but for only one row, i have 52 weeks. Have you any solutions ?

Comment: @JérémyBloy you only mentioned one in your original question, post another question with the exact requirements and someone will be able to help you, if not tag me in the question and I will try to respond to it.